# Running a java file from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I run/launch from Eclipse, a java file that would other wise be run with command line arguments? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What has regex tag to do within this question?

Comment: It's a java file doing regex operations and needs command line arguments. Maybe I should have mentioned that in my posting too. Sorry about that.

Comment: But the question is not about regexes, so that tag was inappropriate.  I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Create your class, for Example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CmdExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    }

}
```

1. Right click on the file in the "Package Explorer"-View
2. "Run as>"
3. "2 Java Application"
4. Right click on the file **again** in the "Package Explorer"-View
5. "Run as>"
6. "Run configurations..."
7. Switch to tab "Arguments"
8. enter your command line arguments in "Program arguments"
9. click "Run"

Answer (score 0):

First launch the main class, and then locate the launch configuration where you can add command line parameters and set system properties, etc.